# How do deep learning libraries implicity find operations on variables that don't call library functions?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

For instance, in Tensorflow, 
`tf.matmul(x, y)` is equivalent to `x @ y` in python3.5+.
How does Tensorflow implicitly know to add the `x @ y` operation to the graph if there is no function telling it to? Is it done in the C back-ends? I've searched around and found nothing of the likes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with the use of operator overloading.

`x` and `y` both have type `Tensor`. Tensor has implemented `__matmul__` method (which corresponds to `@` operator).

`__matmul__` implementation might look like this:

```
def __matmul__(self, other):
    return tf.matmul(self, other)
```

Offical documentation on operator overloading: [link](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).